# Borrar objeto o fila seleccionada desde un jTable con Serialización

Tags: java, array, java-swing, serialización

Estoy haciendo uso de la serialización y quisiera saber como puedo hacer para borrar un objeto que ya he seleccionado en un jTable. Para llenar el jTable con datos utilizo un ArrayList.

No se como obtener el índice del objeto en la tabla para luego pasarlo al ArrayList y borrarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar usando el método getSelectedRows()

```
public void removeSelectedRows(JTable table){
   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) this.table.getModel();
   int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
   for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
     model.removeRow(rows[i]-i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Gracias @JoelIbaceta pero eso solo lo elimina de la tabla tengo un ArrayLsit desde el cual introduzco datos hacia la clase serializada y cuando introduzco un nuevo contacto o cuando actualizo la tabla el mismo objeto que borre vuelve a aparecer porque lo borre de la tabla no del ArrayList, a eso me refiero a borrar la fila seleccionada en la tabla en el ArrayList

Comment: Resulta que cuando asignas los valores de un ArrayList a un JTable la lista es recorrida y los valores son asignados a los campos del JTable por lo que no tendría por que mantener los indices, para hacer lo que buscas es necesario que tengas una columna con algún valor que identifique al registro por ejemplo "id" al obtener la fila seleccionada leerías este valor, recorrerías el ArrayList y el obtener el id cuando el elemento coincida con el valor de la columna id.

Comment: Gracias @JoelIbaceta, creí que podía borrar una columna solo con seleccionarla.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando pasas un arrayList a un Jtable pasa tal y cual en el orden del array. Puede servirte la fila seleccionada para borrar directamente en el array. Ten cuidado de no ordenar por columnas (eso lo permite la cabecera del jtable). Agregues o elimines registros sera tambien directo en el ArrayList. Suerte

Comment: para que tu respuesta sea completa, debes completarla con codigo, sino lo tuyo es mas bien un comentario.